# Conflict with AppTheme my app cant use built-in actionBar but one of the library require actionBar in AppTheme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, app-themes

If i use AppTheme without ActionBar than i get crash when i call WeAccept Payment SDK because they require Actionbar to be available in AppTheme.

My code :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/DefaultPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/DefaultPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/DefaultAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/DefaultPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And in `Manifest` 
i use `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`

Note : i cant display the default ActionBar in my application because if the custom design

Comment: For the activity of that library, you can declare the theme which is required by that activity.

Comment: i cant control that activity because its in their sdk to allow the user to enter his visa info

Comment: I think you are declaring that activity in your manifest file. There you can apply theme.

Comment: no this is my code :Intent pay_intent = new Intent(this, PayActivity.class);

        putNormalExtras(pay_intent);
        pay_intent.putExtra(PayActivityIntentKeys.SAVE_CARD_DEFAULT, true);
        pay_intent.putExtra(PayActivityIntentKeys.SHOW_ALERTS, showSaveCard);
        pay_intent.putExtra(PayActivityIntentKeys.SHOW_SAVE_CARD, showSaveCard);
        pay_intent.putExtra(PayActivityIntentKeys.THEME_COLOR, 0x8033B5E5);

        startActivityForResult(pay_intent, ACCEPT_PAYMENT_REQUEST);
and that activity in their sdk package com.paymob.acceptsdk;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With himanshu help i managed to get it working after creating new theme with different name in styles and adding that sdk activity in my main manifest (it seems that it will override their manifest).

```
<activity
    android:name="com.paymob.acceptsdk.PayActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemePayment" />
```